# Page environment is blocking angularjs bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My angularjs 1.5 application is running in an MS Dynamics 365 environment inside an iFrame on the actual page.

Anyway, it seems like that angularjs is waiting until all JS-operations from Dynamics, even outside the frame (script-loading etc.), have been finished and only then it's going to bootstrap the actual own app.

That causes many performance loading problems.
I understand that it could (not sure) be in angulars nature to wait for all scripts cause there could be something relevant for it's execution. 
But if there are many other not relevant scripts on that page, it causes huge problems.

Is there a way to say "Hey angular! Wait for the scripts "jQuery.js, module1.js" etc." and then you are allowed to bootstrap because thats actually all what you need"?

Comment: not really an answer to your question, but if you are running angular in an iFrame inside any other environment, it shouldn't really know what is happening outside that iFrame. perhaps the iFrame isn't rendered by the 'host' application (Dynamics?) until everything else is loaded. that means angular isn't where your problem lies.

Comment: also ; angularJS (which is really angular 1.0) and angular (2.0 or later) are very different. it might help to know which you are using.

Comment: I specified the version to 1.5. Thanks for that hint.

Comment: Yep, I also thought that the iFrame should be independent of that host application (yes, it's the dynamics) but you can definitively see that the apps only starts loading if the other things have been loaded.

Comment: If that iFrame is inserted into the page using jQuery (especially if it waits for the entire DOM to load), then this makes perfect sense. or are you certain that the iFrame is there *before* the 'DOM loaded' event triggers?

Comment: I have to check that! Thx!

Comment: so, was that the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just to put the right facts in context, iframes are loaded asynchronously, which means immediately your page is loading it kicks off as well. Now, you can manually control the loading behavior of the iframe by deferring when its loaded into the DOM using a Javascript code that creates the iframe:

```
function createIframe() {
    let iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.src = "<angularjs-app-url>";
    iframe.scrolling = "auto";
    iframe.frameborder = "0";
    iframe.width = "200px";
    iframe.height = "100px";
    document.getElementById("div-that-holds-the-iframe").appendChild(iframe);
}
```

Then you can check if the JS files: jquery.js, module1.js are loaded before calling the createIframe() function:

```
window.onload = function() {
    if (window.jquery && module1){
        createIframe();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a script which load the iframe and then add the attribute defer in the call:

```
<script src="yourscrypt.js" defer></script>
```

See more in:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp